# How to use shared preference on favorite button in flutter to maintain the state of a favorited item even if the app is closed and reopened

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

How to use shared preference for favorite button in Flutter to favorited items remain even after the app is closed and reopened. [Image of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsyXq.gif)

I tried several tutorials on the internet but non is working for me. I want to be able to use shared preference to save the state of the favorited item so that when I favorite something and close the app it will still be favorited when I reopen the app at another time.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class FavoriteProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  //List<String> _words = [];  //List<String> get words => _words;
  List<Item> _foundUsers = [];
  List<Item> get words => _foundUsers;

  toggleFavorite(Item item) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final isExist = _foundUsers.contains(item);

    if (isExist) {
      _foundUsers.remove(item);
      sharedPreferences.setBool('is_save', true);
    } else {
      _foundUsers.add(item);
      sharedPreferences.setBool('is_save', false);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  bool isExist(Item item) {
    final isExist = _foundUsers.contains(item);
    return isExist;
  }

  void clearFavorite() {
    _foundUsers = [];
    notifyListeners();
  }

  static FavoriteProvider of(
    BuildContext context, {
    bool listen = true,
  }) {
    return Provider.of<FavoriteProvider>(
      context,
      listen: listen,
    );
  }
}
```

```
                                trailing: IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    provider.toggleFavorite(word);
                                  },
                                  icon: provider.isExist(word)
                                      ? const Icon(Icons.favorite,
                                          color: Colors.red)
                                      : const Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                                ),
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! please [edit] your question to exlain what's _exactly_ is the problem, are you receiving any stacktraces? _"I tried several tutorials on the internet but non is working for me"_ doesnt help explain the problem.

Comment: I'd put the source of truth about the state of the toggle into a riverpod provider, then use the .listenSelf callback to update the value in shared preferences and a build that fetches the initial value from shared preferences, or provides a default value